# How to read contents of a file in PHP

Tags: php, file

I want to know how to read a file. Below is the code I'm executing but I get the wrong answer. My file `ding.txt` contains:

```
name, drinks,
jay, sprite,
chile, wine,
```

My code:

```
<?php
$top = file('ding.txt');
foreach($top as $trick)
{
    $m = preg_split( "/,/", $trick);

    foreach($m as $t)
    { 
        echo "$t[1]";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Take the time to write a good question (if needed, once you have already make some research).

Comment: @casimir et Hoppolyte I just want to know where my error is in this question.Thank-you!!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i was expecting when I do echo  $t[1] to spit out jay, but its a wrong output being displayed.

Comment: so ding.txt only contains a string? or are all 6 of those variables? Or are those 6 items the contents of an array?

Comment: @jajoshi: take a look at the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wonder if if my preg_split is correct as written

Comment: @chris Haugen ding.txt contains a string CSV.

Comment: You can't loop through a string. You need to put each of those items in an array.

Comment: @Chris Haugen can you please show me how to put it in a array. I am confused because I thought $m is an array of CSV values.

Comment: `$m` is a variable. my answer below should be everything you need. take a look at the documentation I linked to it's really easy to create arrays :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you use either include, or require.

in ding.txt make that string an array.

Here's documentation on arrays: [array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

so it should be:

```
<?php
$top = include 'ding.txt';
foreach($top as $trick)
{
global $array;

foreach($array as $t)

{ 

echo "$t[1]"; //1 would echo the first array item
}

?>
```

Although, If you want to loop through some variables in that file, then I would declare the variables as global variables so you can loop through them after you include the ding.txt file.

check out this resource for globals, and to better understand scope, which is what your question is all about:

[globals & scope documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: It is the very first time I see an accepted answer with negative votes. Just in case, you are solving the problem in very complex way. Try to avoid using `include` statement and avoid using `global` vars

Answer (score 0):

For educational purposes i won't change your code.

With this you can see in your browser what's happening : (with brackets you can't miss the white spaces)

```
$top = file('ding.txt');
foreach($top as $trick)
{
    echo "<br>\$trick = '{$trick}'<br>";
    $m = preg_split( "/,/", $trick);

    foreach($m as $t)
    { 
        echo " \$t = '{$t}'<br>";
        //echo "$t[1]";
    }
}
```

My output :

```
$trick = 'name, drinks, '
$t = 'name'
$t = ' drinks'
$t = ' '

$trick = 'jay, sprite, '
$t = 'jay'
$t = ' sprite'
$t = ' '

$trick = 'chile, wine, '
$t = 'chile'
$t = ' wine'
$t = ' '
```

If we take this line for example :

```
$t = ' drinks'
```

If you understand tables, it should be obvious that :

```
$t[0] will be ' '
$t[1] will be 'd'
etc...
```

Edit : a foreach loop IS NOT a for loop